# Accessing a variable in the success callback for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script I made to ajax submit any form with the id of `ajax`. In the success callback function, I want to check to see if `data-after` is set on the current form I'm on because there are multiple forms with multiple `data-after` attributes.  then `console.log()`.

```
$('form#ajax').on('submit', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#console p').text(response);
            if (that.attr('data-after').length) {
                // Use data-after to change the text of elements inside current form
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

`that` is undefined in the callback.

Comment: Why do you re-define `that` in your `.each()` function? It might be that that's causing the variable to be overwritten inside that scope, deleting it from its previous scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by passing in that and create a callback closure.

```
success: function(that){
     return function (response) {
            $('#console p').text(response);
            if (that.attr('data-after').length) {
                // Use data-after to change the text of elements inside current form
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
      }(that);
```

Comment: This is not console logging what I have in `data-after`. What I am intending to do is take the value of `data-after` and assign it to the element which is a submit button. So on submit and success, change the value of the submit button showing the form was sent.